# Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined, using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Hello so i am trying to learn how to do a drawing app using HTML5 canvas
and i wrote this code so far, the thing is the browser console keeps telling me that Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined, i am using jquery of course

here is the JS code:

```
var canvas;
var context;


function getMousePos(e) {
    var canBoundX = canvas.offsetLeft;
    var canBoundY = canvas.offsetTop;
    var x = e.clientX - canBoundX,
        y = e.clientY - canBoundY;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}


function drag_click() {
    console.log(getMousePos());
}

function drag() {
    console.log(getMousePos());
}

function drag_stop() {
    console.log(getMousePos());
}

function draw() {
    canvas = $("#mainCanvas")[0];
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle =  "#000";
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.lineCap = "round";

    $(canvas).mousedown(function (e) {
        drag_click();
    });
    $(canvas).mousemove(function (e) {
        drag();
    });
    $(canvas).mouseup(function (e) {
        drag_stop();
    });
}


$(document).ready(draw());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass argument `e` in functions `draw_click`, `draw` and `draw_stop`, and also in function `get_mouse_pos`. When you pass no arguments, in function `get_mouse_pos` variable `e` is `undefined`.

```
var canvas;
var context;


function getMousePos(e) {
    var canBoundX = canvas.offsetLeft;
    var canBoundY = canvas.offsetTop;
    var x = e.clientX - canBoundX,
        y = e.clientY - canBoundY;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}


function drag_click(e) {
    console.log(getMousePos(e));
}

function drag(e) {
    console.log(getMousePos(e));
}

function drag_stop(e) {
    console.log(getMousePos(e));
}

function draw() {
    canvas = $("#mainCanvas")[0];
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle =  "#000";
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.lineCap = "round";

    $(canvas).mousedown(function (e) {
        drag_click(e);
    });
    $(canvas).mousemove(function (e) {
        drag(e);
    });
    $(canvas).mouseup(function (e) {
        drag_stop(e);
    });
}


$(document).ready(draw());
```

Comment: i passed e, in all the functions before and yet it didin't work and trued again and didn't work, am sure it has to do with Jquery and the way it handle events i just can't figure it out

Comment: @J.Duo. I am still not sure you passed arguments correctly. Try copy-pasting my code.

Comment: copy pasting worked, am so ashamed missing something like this but it's okay never going to happen again :D

Comment: I had same problem and I did `d3.event.clientY`